# Where are the view classes Play generates from your scala templates?

Tags: playframework

I am following http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/JavaGuide4 and get a compilation error saying "login.render()" is not valid with no arguments.  This is funny because eclipse complains about a different line: "login.render(loginForm)".  I typed "play compile" to compile, same results.

According to http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/ScalaTemplates
once I create the scala view template login.scala.html, play generates the class views.html.Application.login.  I'd like to see the render method of this generated class, where is the class located?  Thanks.  btw here are my imports:

```
import play.*;
import play.mvc.*;
import views.html.*;
import play.data.*;
import play.libs.F.Function;
import play.libs.F.Promise;
import play.libs.WS;
import play.libs.WS.Response;
import play.Logger;
import play.data.Form.*;
import views.html.*;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find the the generated Scala templates in `YOUR_PROJECT_FOLDER/target/scala-2.10/src_managed/main/views/html/..`

They're generated as Scala source files, and be prepared for them to be an unreadable mess.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out it wasn't a real error, just something eclipse couldn't handle without the eclipse scala ide plugin: http://scala-ide.org/download/sdk.html